# Should everyone take the ebola vaccine to achieve global herd immunity?

Tags: immune-system, vaccination, virus, ebola

> Ebola virus disease (EVD), also known as Ebola hemorrhagic fever (EHF) or simply Ebola, is a viral hemorrhagic fever of humans and other primates caused by ebolaviruses. <sup>1</sup>

Should everyone in the world take the ebola vaccine <sup>2</sup> to achieve global herd immunity <sup>3</sup> against the ebola virus disease <sup>4</sup>?

Similar to the way herd immunity was achieved with the eradication of smallpox in 1977.

---

<sup>1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebola_virus_disease</sup>
<sup>2 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebola_vaccine</sup>
<sup>3 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_immunity</sup>
<sup>4 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebola_virus_disease</sup>

Comment: Unlikely that a program of mass vaccination would be required - ring vaccination is what was used in the elimination of Smallpox and IIRC is the current tack being taken with Ebola.